# Why does PublicKey.isOnCurve always return false?

Tags: web3.js

I am in the process of creating token transfer transactions, but getting the address' associated token account throws an error, saying it isn't on the curve.
So, I tested PublicKey.isOnCurve for [my address](https://solscan.io/account/4Zf48t1zUP8Lz2atAK8NkEiLf7CfT5fFoAR6Nsk4Saip) and for randomly generated ones.

my code:
[image]

terminal output:
[image]

for some reason, this only happens in this specific project; when I run it on a clean node project it prints true for these values.

Answer (score 5):

There was a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200948/how-can-i-validate-a-solana-wallet-address-with-web3js.
The issue here seems to be that isOnCurve expects a Uint8Array. Consider trying publicKey.toBytes() to get the byte array representation of your key.

Comment: I didn't fix this issue completely. It works correctly in the browser, but not in node (or the jest test I was running). I see that @solana/web3.js has different modules for in the browser, so maybe there is an issue there.